# Remember form selection

Tags: django, drop-down-menu, django-templates

How to "remember" form selection value in Django?

```html
{% load i18n %}
<form action="." method="GET" name="perpage" >
<select name="perpage">
    {% for choice in choices %}
    <option value="{{choice}}" {% if 'choice' == choice %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>
        {% if choice == 0 %}{% trans "All" %}{% else %}{{choice}}{% endif %}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Select' %}" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your code here. We don't want to follow a link (which may become invalid) to find out what your code is or to find out that the majority of it is irrelevant.

Comment: okay, sure! do you know, what IF must be in line 5?

Comment: This depends entirely on how you're processing this form. Does the context contain the selected choice somewhere to match this against? Are you asking if it can default to the last selected choice? Because thsi form doens't appear to have any validation anyways.

Comment: i don't need any validation. all that i need - remember selected option. i use session for saving option value in cache, but i don't know how to remember my choice on form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@register.inclusion_tag('pagination/perpageselect.html', takes_context='True')
def perpageselect (context, *args):
  """
  Reads the arguments to the perpageselect tag and formats them correctly.
  """
  try:
      choices = [int(x) for x in args]
      perpage = int(context['request'].perpage)
      return {'choices': choices, 'perpage': perpage}
  except(TypeError, ValueError):
      raise template.TemplateSyntaxError(u'Got %s, but expected integer.' % args)
```

i just added `takes_context='True'` and take the value from context. The template i edited as

```
{% load i18n %}
 <form action="." method="GET" name="perpage" >
 <select name="perpage">
    {% for choice in choices %}
    <option value="{{choice}}" {% if perpage = choice %} selected="selected" {% endif%}>
        {% if choice == 0 %}{% trans "All" %}{% else %}{{choice}}{% endif %}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Select' %}" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

sorry about my words, but this seems a bad aproach. The django way to work with this is a simple [form with a initial value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) for your selected choice. If you don't belive me, and you persist in this way, then change your [template if](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#operator) as:

```
{% if choice == myInitChoice %}
```

Don't forget to send `myInitChoice` to context.

```
c = RequestContext(request, {
    'myInitChoice': request.session.get( 'yourInitValue', None ),
})
return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Comment: hi @yakudza_m, there is another way to say thanks, one day you will discover it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you run into a common tasks, chances are there is an easy way to do it in django.

```
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

FIELD_CHOICES=((5,"Five"),(10,"Ten"),(20,"20"))

class MyForm(froms.Form):
    perpage = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FIELD_CHOICES)


def show_form(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = MyForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             return redirect('/thank-you')
          else:
              return render(request,'form.html',{'form':form})
      else:
          form = MyForm()
           return render(request,'form.html',{'form':form})
```

In your template:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {{ form.errors }}
{% endif %}

<form method="POST" action=".">
  {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form }}
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```